# how to make website, use distributed file system- hadoop for data management

Tags: hadoop, web, bigdata, distributed-system

I am naive in big data technology, and have curiosity to relate it with the conventional application development.

The conventional way to develop any web application is to have a hosting server (or application server) and a database to manage the data.
But lets say, I have a huge data set which is generated by the website, (i.e. GBs per second), then the website will fall into the category of managing big data.

lets suppose, I have a cluster of 20 computers, with 200GB of hard drives and core i3 processor. So now I will have enough processing and storage power for the website. (of-course hadoop is scalable too, if I need more resources).
how to setup application server, to host the website in this cluster ?
will I need load balancers for my application server since there is higher velocity, of http request to the application server? 
can anyone please guide !
thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I just wanted to take an overview idea of how web application development takes place in relation with big data. Let's imagine Facebook. It is basically a web application. How application servers and database management is done, for Facebook is my curiosity.
As it is a fact that such a big company like Facebook, will have to use distributed system. E.g. hadoop clusters. And my question relates with the same concept. But Facebook has huge clusters, and to understand the way it has been implemented is tough, in my question I mentioned cluster of 20 computers. If someone has experience in setting up the hadoop clusters for web application hosting, then I would request to share the knowledge

Comment: There is no where near enough information to guess at the right answer.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning. I just wanted to take an overview idea of how web application development takes place in relation with big data.
Let's imagine Facebook. It is basically a web application. How application servers and database management is done, for Facebook is my curiosity.

Comment: As it is a fact that such a big company like Facebook, will have to use distributed system. E.g. hadoop clusters. And my question relates with the same concept. But Facebook has huge clusters, and to understand the way it has been implemented is tough, in my question I mentioned cluster of 20 computers. If someone has experience in setting up the hadoop clusters for web application hosting, then I would request to share the knowledge.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Hadoop, but if I were going to make a web site I would use Visual Studio.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4cbh4dh.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIRmPB0xshw

Visual Studio Express is free and very easy to use.